# What is a tools:itemCount equivalent for ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, expandablelistview

[`RecyclerView` offers a convenient way to preview the layout](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolsitemcount) in Android Studio's tab called Design:

```
tools:itemCount
```

Is there any equivalent for `ExpandableListView`?

I assume the answer is "no" because I found that a different tool, `tools:listitem` does work for `ExpandableListView`.  I believe that's explained by its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolslistitem_toolslistheader_toolslistfooter), "Intended for: `<AdapterView>` (and subclasses like `<ListView>`)".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Each `tools:` attribute belongs to different class.

You could integrate these two attributes like below.

The main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        tools:listitem="@layout/sample_list_item" //notice this line
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The sample_list_item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:itemCount="3"  //notice this line
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Now you will see in preview as below fig:
[image]

notice there are three items shown.

Comment: The `ExpandableListView` is repeated without apparent limit.